# Seeking code example for OAuth 2.0 with Google Ad Exchange seller-API

Tags: php, api, google-api-php-client

First things first:

The goal is to pull reports from via ADX seller API.

I followed the tutorial, created a Project in the GDC, activated the adx-seller-API and added an OAuth 2.0 client ID just to make sure both types, `"Web application"` and `"Other"`.

The code is easy enough, I got the `google-api-php-client` via `composer` and used the minimal example:

```
<?php
  require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setAuthConfigFile('client_secrets.json');
  $client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adexcange.seller');

  $service = new Google_Service_AdExchangeSeller($client);  

  $result =  $service->accounts->listAccounts();
  print_r($result);
?>
```

However running the code only yields an exception:

```
Google_Service_Exception: { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "required", "message": "Login Required", "locationType": "header", "location": "Authorization" } ], "code": 401, "message": "Login Required" } } in [SNIP]\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Http\REST.php on line 105
```

So basically `401: Login required`

I also used both generated `JSON` for client_secrets.json, only the `"other"` one works.

If I use the `Google API Explorer` it works just fine, oddly the `accountId` that is talked of everywhere seems to be the `DFP-ADX Publisher ID` in case anyone is ever wondering.

I've no idea why this isn't working? Am I missing something important or doing something wrong?

In case it helps, I tried the same with Python, for some reason I get as far as to the authentication via browser, the adexchangeseller.dat is created and then it pops a `403: User does not have an Ad Exchange Seller account.` which is hilarious considering it does and works via Google API Explorer.

Any help, even a push towards a decent tutorial is appreciated a lot of researching only led to dead ends.

Comment: You have to go through the OAuth system of logging in and getting a Auth Token for an individual user. `$client->createAuthUrl()` will get you your login url then you need to go through the process of getting the code and verifying it.

Comment: Once you have the token you will need to set it on your client, `$client->setAccessToken($token);`

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll check this out tomorrow. Seems the google code examples are rather incomplete and left me hanging.

Comment: Many of the tutorials will need to be updated as the PHP Google API client has recently been upgraded to 2.0 and is constantly in development. It broke my application, but since it is still in early stages, I will upgrade to 2.x. See [UPGRADING.md](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/UPGRADING.md) for migrating from 1.x to 2

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I have the exact same problem.